# JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512) even with out Native Code

Tags: android

we recently launched our app and upgrade actually from previous version..

and suddenly we started to see this error in a ton of devices ..we have no clue whats happening and the logs are very vague ..

Attaching the logs here .But any help or some clue might help us debug the issue .

---

Build fingerprint: 'Verizon/zeroltevzw/zeroltevzw:5.1.1/LMY47X/G925VVRU4BOK7:user/release-keys'

Revision: '10'

ABI: 'arm64'

pid: 31610, tid: 31610, name: st.mediamanager  >>>  <<<

signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------

Abort message: 'sart/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:98] JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)'

```
x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000007b7a  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000007fa219fe30

x4   0000007fa219fe30  x5   0000000000000005  x6   0000000000000001  x7   0000000000000020

x8   0000000000000083  x9   00000000000000ca  x10  0000007fa1f2a000  x11  0000000000000001

x12  0000000000000001  x13  0000007fa1f2a000  x14  c4aa4c0daad90e20  x15  0000007f92002a31

x16  0000007fa1f2a610  x17  0000007fa1eca174  x18  0000000000000000  x19  0000007fa219fe30

x20  0000007fa21a00e8  x21  0000007fa1f30000  x22  0000000000000001  x23  0000000000000006

x24  0000007fee90e2d0  x25  0000007f9e0a6000  x26  0000007fee90e2c8  x27  0000007f9dffd520

x28  0000007f9e0a6000  x29  0000007fee90e150  x30  0000007fa1e8c264

sp   0000007fee90e150  pc   0000007fa1eca17c  pstate 0000000060000000
```

backtrace:

```
#00 pc 000000000005e17c  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)

#01 pc 0000000000020260  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+160)

#02 pc 0000000000021794  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+28)

#03 pc 000000000001b17c  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+60)

#04 pc 0000000000310534  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+300)

#05 pc 00000000000d5378  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+2684)

#06 pc 00000000001e7ff0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::IndirectReferenceTable::Add(unsigned int, art::mirror::Object*)+416)

#07 pc 00000000002e28cc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::VMClassLoader_findLoadedClass(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jobject*, _jstring*)+248)

#08 pc 000000000002a5dc  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat
```

---

Build fingerprint: 'Verizon/trltevzw/trltevzw:5.1.1/LMY47X/N910VVRU2BPA1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '12'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 481, tid: 481, name: st.mediamanager  >>>  <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'sart/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:109] JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)'
    r0 00000000  r1 000001e1  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
    r4 b6fc3e38  r5 00000006  r6 00000016  r7 0000010c
    r8 00000000  r9 b486f550  sl b4827800  fp 00000475
    ip 000001e1  sp bebbaaf8  lr b6e22715  pc b6e46854  cpsr 60070010

backtrace:
    #00 pc 00038854  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    #01 pc 00014711  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
    #02 pc 0001532f  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    #03 pc 00011bc9  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
    #04 pc 0001003c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    #05 pc 00230cd1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+160)
    #06 pc 000ac58b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1322)
    #07 pc 0016996d  /system/lib/libart.so (art::IndirectReferenceTable::Add(unsigned int, art::mirror::Object*)+244)
    #08 pc 00214f43  /system/lib/libart.so (art::VMClassLoader_findLoadedClass(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jobject*, _jstring*)+162)
    #09 pc 0001bd8d  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat

---

Build fingerprint: 'Verizon/zenltevzw/zenltevzw:5.1.1/LMY47X/G928VVRU2AOJ3:user/release-keys'
Revision: '9'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 18658, tid: 18658, name: st.mediamanager  >>> <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'sart/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:109] JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)'
    x0   0000000000000000  x1   00000000000048e2  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000007fa3887e30
    x4   0000007fa3887e30  x5   0000000000000005  x6   0000000000000001  x7   0000000000000020
    x8   0000000000000083  x9   000000000000005e  x10  0000007fa3613000  x11  0000000000000001
    x12  0000000000000001  x13  0000007fa3613000  x14  24d3f27831b256ef  x15  0000000000000001
    x16  0000007fa3613610  x17  0000007fa35b30d4  x18  0000000000000000  x19  0000007fa3887e30
    x20  0000007fa38880e8  x21  0000007fa3619000  x22  0000000000000001  x23  0000000000000006
    x24  0000007fc7e2cbc0  x25  0000007f9f820d40  x26  0000000000000001  x27  0000007f8c101b60
    x28  0000000000000000  x29  0000007fc7e2ca40  x30  0000007fa3575224
    sp   0000007fc7e2ca40  pc   0000007fa35b30dc  pstate 0000000060000000

backtrace:

```
#00 pc 000000000005e0dc  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
#01 pc 0000000000020220  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+160)
#02 pc 0000000000021754  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+28)
#03 pc 000000000001b13c  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+60)
#04 pc 00000000002ffca4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+300)
#05 pc 00000000000d15b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+2684)
#06 pc 00000000002ad730  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Monitor::VisitLocks(art::StackVisitor*, void (*)(art::mirror::Object*, void*), void*, bool)+952

#07 pc 0000000000314978  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::StackDumpVisitor::VisitFrame()+568)
#08 pc 000000000030ba08  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::StackVisitor::WalkStack(bool)+308)
#09 pc 0000000000313754  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpJavaStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+268)
#10 pc 0000000000313968  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+272)
#11 pc 000000000031e8dc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::DumpLocked(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&)+100)
#12 pc 00000000002ffd34  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+444)
#13 pc 00000000000d15b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+2684)
#14 pc 00000000001d7468  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::IndirectReferenceTable::Add(unsigned int, art::mirror::Object*)+416)
#15 pc 00000000002d2018  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::VMClassLoader_findLoadedClass(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jobject*, _jstring*)+248)
#16 pc 000000000002a5dc  /system/framework/arm64/boot.oat
```

---

Build fingerprint: 'Verizon/kltevzw/kltevzw:5.0/LRX21T/G900VVRU2BOK3:user/release-keys'

Revision: '14'

ABI: 'arm'

pid: 32148, tid: 32148, name: st.mediamanager  >>>  <<<

signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------

Abort message: 'art/runtime/indirect_reference_table.cc:113] JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)'

```
r0 00000000  r1 00007d94  r2 00000006  r3 00000000

r4 b6f92114  r5 00000006  r6 00000016  r7 0000010c

r8 00000000  r9 b4e4f520  sl b4e07800  fp 000004ba

ip 00007d94  sp be8a3b38  lr b6f1bfd1  pc b6f40268  cpsr 60070010
```

backtrace:

```
#00 pc 00038268  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)

#01 pc 00013fcd  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)

#02 pc 00014beb  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)

#03 pc 00011531  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)

#04 pc 0000fcbc  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)

#05 pc 0021d5d9  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+160)

#06 pc 000a834b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+1322)

#07 pc 001574b7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::IndirectReferenceTable::Add(unsigned int, art::mirror::Object*)+346)

#08 pc 002010d5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::VMClassLoader_findLoadedClass(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jobject*, _jstring*)+136)


#09 pc 0001b151  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer, but its too lengthy for a comment so I'll post it as one.

So the error is just what you expect-  its a call into native code that causes you to have more than 512 objects shared with native.  Usually that happens because of a leak somewhere.  And you don't need to be using native code directly to do it-  the framework makes a LOT of native calls behind the scenes.

From the stack trace-  I see its libart.so, not libdalvik.so.  So this is happening on new devices which have switched from the Dalvik VM to Art.  The stack trace looks like it was trying to load a class and add a reference to it for some JNI code, but I can't be certain of that.  I do know that we've seen class loading bugs at work on Art that didn't exist on dalvik.

If you have any native code at all I'd make sure you were releasing all reference to java memory and classes properly.  If you don't-  this may be a bug in Art, knowing what the app was doing at the time of the crash would be useful.  Is the crash consistent?  If so, what are you doing?

Comment: we just started seeing it in Google play crashes. None of us in the company are able to reproduce it or none of us found this error during our QA cycles. We just happend to see a lot of these in crash reports . May be the crash is consistent but at this point we have no more details than those logs.